Does $x^2+y$ represent infinitely many primes, where $|y|<|x|$?
Is the number of primes represented by the $P(x,y)=x^2+y$ infinite under the restriction that $|y|<|x|$, and $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$? Surely yes if we assume Bunyakovsky's conjecture. Is there another way around? Thank you a lot!

Are $x,y$ supposed to be integers?

All primes $p > 2$ can be represented this way.  Let $x$ be the nearest integer to $\sqrt{p}$. So $|x -\sqrt{p}|< 1/2$, i.e. $x-1/2 < \sqrt{p} < x + 1/2$, and that says $x^2 - x + 1/4 < p < x^2 + x + 1/4$. Since $p$ and $x^2 + x$ are integers,
$x^2 - x < p \le x^2 + x$. But $x^2 + x = x (x+1)$ is not a prime unless $x = 1$ (which corresponds to $p = 2$).
So $x^2 - x < p < x^2 + x$,  i.e. $y = p - x^2$ satisfies $|y| < x$.

For each $x=n$, $y$ can take values in the range $[-n+1 \ , \ n-1]$. This for $x^2+y$ gives us the integers in the range $[n^2-n+1 \ , \ n^2+n-1]$. In total, the attainable integers are
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \ \{ x \}_{x=n^2-n+1}^{n^2+n-1} \ = \ \mathbb N \ \setminus \ \{n^2+n\}_{n=1}^\infty .$$
The latter set includes all primes other than $2$, so the answer is $\boxed{\text{yes}}$.
